# Getting a filename_list is not defined

Tags: jquery

I made a loop in my jquery so that I can get a list of all the images that I've dragged over. I'm able to get the list of images, but I'm now trying to push it into an array so that I can use it somewhere else in my code.

Here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

    var filename_list = [];
    dropZone.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        for(x = 0; x < e.dataTransfer.files.length; x++)
        {
        //Gets the list of names from when I dragged images over
            var filename = e.dataTransfer.files[x].name

            //Pushing the list of filenames into an array
            filename_list.push(filename);
        }

    }

    //Trying to use the filename array outside of the loop
    console.log('filename - '+filename_list);

    dropZone.ondragover = function(e){
        return false;
    }

    dropZone.ondragleave = function(){
        return false;
    }
});
```

snippet here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

  var filename_list = [];
  dropZone.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (x = 0; x < e.dataTransfer.files.length; x++) {
      //Gets the list of names from when I dragged images over
      var filename = e.dataTransfer.files[x].name

      //Pushing the list of filenames into an array
      filename_list.push(filename);
    }

  }

  //Trying to use the filename array outside of the function
  console.log('filename - ' + filename_list);

  dropZone.ondragover = function(e) {
    return false;
  }

  dropZone.ondragleave = function() {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.upload-console {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.upload-console-header {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop.drop {
  border-color: #222;
  color: #222;
}

.upload-console-body {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar-fill {
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
}

.bar-fill-text {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.upload-console-upload {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.upload-console-upload span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">content</label>
    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="standard-upload-files" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload files" id="standard-upload">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upload-console">
      <h2 class="upload-console-header">
        Upload
      </h2>

      <div class="upload-console-body">
        <div class="upload-console-drop" id="drop-zone">
          just drag and drop files here
        </div>

        <div class="bar">
          <div class="bar-fill" id="bar-fill">
            <div class="bar-fill-text" id="bar-fill-text"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden" id="uploads-finished">
          <h3>Process files</h3>
          <div class="upload-console-upload">
            <a href="#">filename.jpg</a>
            <span>Success</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" name="add_product" id="add_item">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a slightly working copy of my code. [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Shiva478/pen/YzzYejN)

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  Can you add your HTML and make this example runnable to demonstrate?

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example in codepen

Comment: I'm not able to generate an error there.  Is there something specific that needs to be done to replicate the problem?

Comment: I don't get an error. When I `console.log(filename_list)` I don't get anything.

Comment: *"I don't get an error"* - That makes the title of the question a bit misleading.  More specifically, what exactly are you expecting to log?  There's only one place in the code where you log that to the console, and it's (a) combined with a string and the array itself isn't a string and (b) an empty array.  Can you clarify exactly what the problem is that you're trying to describe?

Comment: So what I'm trying to get is the filename to be in an array and for me to be able to use it outside of the `dropZone.ondrop` function. Because what I would like to do is be able to then submit that filename along with some textboxes using ajax, but I can't do that until I can get the filename. Does this help?

Comment: Well, you can use it outside the `ondrop` function, and you currently do.  When you use it in this code it's still empty.  *After* you've dropped a file there, it should have the value from that file.  Where do you try to use it *after* dropping a file?  Where are you submitting anything via AJAX?  In what way is *that* code failing?  The nature of the problem seems entirely hidden from the question here.

Comment: I'm not submitting anything at the moment. I want to first get the filenam, before I get that far and after I dropped the file I don't get any feedback in my console. It still stays blank

Comment: Put `console.log(filename_list)` inside the `ondrop` function, you can observe it being populated with each drop.

Comment: So I did that and I still get a blank in my console

Comment: Can you update the runnable example to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

you need to look at the array AFTER it gets populated for the global (bad perhaps do do that) or on an event which I show both.

Also if you pick one, I added that change event.

```js
$(function() {
  // I could also put both events here if I wanted
  $("#standard-upload-files").on('change', function(event) {
    let files = $(this).val();
    console.log('Change files:', files);
  });

  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
  var filename_list = [];
  dropZone.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (x = 0; x < e.dataTransfer.files.length; x++) {
      //Gets the list of names from when I dragged images over
      var filename = e.dataTransfer.files[x].name
      //Pushing the list of filenames into an array
      filename_list.push(filename);
      // trigger AND pass, no global needed
      $(this).trigger('got-dropped', [filename_list]);
    }
  }
  //fails as this happens before it is populated
  console.log('filename:', filename_list);
  $('#drop-zone').on('got-dropped', function(event, files) {
    console.log('filename:', filename_list);
    console.log("files:", files);
  });

  $('input[type=file]').val()
  dropZone.ondragover = function(e) {
    return false;
  }

  dropZone.ondragleave = function() {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.upload-console {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.upload-console-header {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop.drop {
  border-color: #222;
  color: #222;
}

.upload-console-body {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar-fill {
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
}

.bar-fill-text {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.upload-console-upload {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.upload-console-upload span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">content</label>
    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="standard-upload-files" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload files" id="standard-upload">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upload-console">
      <h2 class="upload-console-header">
        Upload
      </h2>

      <div class="upload-console-body">
        <div class="upload-console-drop" id="drop-zone">
          just drag and drop files here
        </div>

        <div class="bar">
          <div class="bar-fill" id="bar-fill">
            <div class="bar-fill-text" id="bar-fill-text"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden" id="uploads-finished">
          <h3>Process files</h3>
          <div class="upload-console-upload">
            <a href="#">filename.jpg</a>
            <span>Success</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" name="add_product" id="add_item">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: note: you could also do this from the handler when you actually pick a file using the button, I added that also

Answer (score 0):

Note that `console.log('filename - '+filename_list)` will always run before the items(file names) are being set. This is because the filename_list is only populated when the  dropZone.ondrop event is called.  If you really want to use the updated filename_list elsewhere then there are two ways to go.

1. Create a callback function which you will call after filename_list has been updated
2. Or Trigger a custom event after filename_list has been updated.

Below is an updated version of the code. The two methods have been demonstrated.

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
    
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

    var filename_list = [];
    dropZone.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        for(x = 0; x < e.dataTransfer.files.length; x++)
        {
        //Gets the list of names from when I dragged images over
            var filename = e.dataTransfer.files[x].name
            
            //Pushing the list of filenames into an array
            filename_list.push(filename);
          console.log('sss',filename_list);
             
        }
        
        //1. You pass it to a function 
        yourCallback(filename_list); 
        //2. Or you can triger another event and listen to it elsewhere
        $(this).trigger('filename_updated',[filename_list]) ;
        
    }
    
    //Trying to use the filename array outside of the function
    //A simple callback function
  
    function yourCallback(list){
      console.log('Your filename_list - ',list);

    }
  
  $('#drop-zone').on('filename_updated', function(event, filenameList) {
    console.log("Your filename_list from filename_updated event", filenameList);
    console.log("Your filename_list from global filename_list variable", filename_list);
  });
  
  
    

    dropZone.ondragover = function(e){
        return false;
    }

    dropZone.ondragleave = function(){
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5{
  font-weight: 400;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.upload-console{
  background: #fefefe;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.upload-console-header{
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop{
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-console-drop.drop{
  border-color: #222;
  color: #222;
}

.upload-console-body{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar{
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar-fill{
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
  transition: width 0.8s ease;
}

.bar-fill-text{
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.upload-console-upload{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.upload-console-upload span{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content">content</label>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="standard-upload-files" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload files" id="standard-upload">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="upload-console">
            <h2 class="upload-console-header">
                Upload
            </h2>

            <div class="upload-console-body">
                <div class="upload-console-drop" id="drop-zone">
                    just drag and drop files here
                </div>

                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="bar-fill" id="bar-fill">
                        <div class="bar-fill-text" id="bar-fill-text"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="hidden" id="uploads-finished">
                    <h3>Process files</h3>

                    <div class="upload-console-upload">
                        <a href="#">filename.jpg</a>
                        <span>Success</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" name="add_product" id="add_item">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Regards